# What the alternative of below pipename for Mac?

Tags: java, macos, named-pipes

I am trying to create a RandomAccessFile with following pipe name. The code is working well in windows. But when i am running it in Mac it is creating a new file 
in Mac instead of accessing the existing pipe.
I have installed Bria in both cases before running the code.

```
new RandomAccessFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\apipipe", "rw")
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://cdimascio.wordpress.com/2014/01/11/named-pipes-with-java/

Comment: Note that your hard-coded pipe name is nonsensical on Unix, as it's a Windows absolute UNC name. You should use a more appropriate name on Unix, and it would be best to make it configurable as a property.